# jq: select only an array which contains element A but not element B

Tags: arrays, json, jq

My data is a series of JSON arrays. Each array has one or more elements with name and id keys:

```
[
  {
    "name": "first_source",
    "id": "abcdef"
  },
  {
    "name": "second_source",
    "id": "ghijkl"
  },
  {
    "name": "third_source",
    "id": "opqrst"
  }
]
```

How, using jq, do I select only the arrays which contain an element with "first source" as the name value, but which don't contain "second_source" as the name value of any element?

This only returns an *element* for further processing:

```
jq '.[] | select (.name == "first_source")
```

But I clearly need to return the entire array for my scenario to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this filter:

```
select(
    (map(.name == "first_source") | any) and
    (map(.name != "second_source") | all)
)
```

You need to test all the elements of an array for an existence of the names.  You can do that by mapping each object to your condition and use the `any` or `all` filter appropriately.

Here, you want to see if any item is named `"first_source"` and all items are not named `"second_source"`.

Comment: When I try that, I get `jq: error (at <stdin>:14): Cannot index string with string "name"`