# jq select elements with array not containing string

Tags: jq, set-intersection

Now, this is somewhat similar to [jq: select only an array which contains element A but not element B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429107/jq-select-only-an-array-which-contains-element-a-but-not-element-b) but it somehow doesn't work for me (which is likely my fault)... ;-)

So here's what we have:

```
[ {

        "employeeType": "student",
        "cn": "dc8aff1",
        "uid": "dc8aff1",
        "ou": [
            "4210910",
            "4210910 #Abg",
            "4210910 Abgang",
            "4240115",
            "4240115 5",
            "4240115 5\/5"
        ]
    },
    {
        "employeeType": "student",
        "cn": "160f656",
        "uid": "160f656",
        "ou": [
            "4210910",
            "4210910 3",
            "4210910 3a"
        ] } ]
```

I'd like to select all elements where ou does **not** contain a specific string, say "4210910 3a" or - which would be even better - where ou does not contain any member of a given list of strings.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to possibly changing inputs, you should make it a parameter to your filter, rather than hardcoding it in.  Also, using `contains` might not work for you in general.  It runs the filter recursively so even substrings will match which might not be preferred.

For example:

```
["10", "20", "30", "40", "50"] | contains(["0"])
```

is `true`

I would write it like this:

```
$ jq --argjson ex '["4210910 3a"]' 'map(select(all(.ou[]; $ex[]!=.)))' input.json
```

Answer (score 1):

This response addresses the case where .ou is an array and we are given another array of forbidden strings.

For clarity, let's define a filter, `intersectq(a;b)`, that will return true iff the arrays have an element in common:

```
def intersectq(a;b):
  any(a[]; . as $x | any( b[]; . == $x) );
```

This is effectively a loop-within-a-loop, but because of the semantics of `any/2`, the computation will stop once a match has been found.(*)

Assuming $ex is the list of exceptions, then the filter we could use to solve the problem would be:

```
map(select(intersectq(.ou; $ex) | not))
```

For example, we could use an invocation along the lines suggested by Jeff:

```
$ jq --argjson ex '["4210910 3a"]' -f myfilter.jq input.json
```

Now you might ask: why use the any-within-any double loop rather than .[]-within-all double loop?  The answer is efficiency, as can be seen using `debug`:

```
$ jq -n '[1,2,3] as $a | [1,1] as $b | all( $a[]; ($b[] | debug) != .)'
["DEBUG:",1]
["DEBUG:",1]
false

$ jq -n '[1,2,3] as $a | [1,1] as $b | all( $a[]; . as $x | all( $b[]; debug | $x != .))'
["DEBUG:",1]
false
```

(*) Footnote

Of course `intersectq/2` as defined here is still O(m*n) and thus inefficient, but the main point of this post is to highlight the drawback of the .[]-within-all double loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that checks the `.ou` member of each element of the input using **foreach** and **contains**.

```
  ["4210910 3a"] as $list   # adjust as necessary

| .[]
| foreach $list[] as $e (
    .; .; if .ou | contains([$e]) then . else empty end
  )
```

EDIT: I now realize a filter of the form `foreach E as $X (.; .; R)` can almost always be rewritten as `E as $X | R` so the above is really just

```
  ["4210910 3a"] as $list
| .[]
| $list[] as $e
| if .ou | contains([$e]) then . else empty end
```